# Combining PDFs with iText results in "Do you want to save changes...?" dialog on close

Tags: java, stream, adobe, arrays, itext

I've seen similar questions here on SO regarding this problem, though mostly in the context of C#/iTextSharp.

I have the following Java method:

```
public byte[] prependCoversheet(byte[] pdfBytes)
{
    InputStream pdfTemplate = getClass().getResourceAsStream("coversheet.pdf");
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(baos1);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos2);

    AcroFields coversheet = stamper.getAcroFields();

    /* Set all the field values here, etc. */
    coversheet.setField("fieldName", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");

    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();

    copy.addDocument(new PdfReader(baos2.toByteArray()));
    copy.addDocument(new PdfReader(pdfBytes));
    copy.close();
    baos.flush();

    return baos1.toByteArray();
}
```

The `byte[]` that is returned is perfectly fine, and opens properly in Adobe Reader (unlike a similar, but probably unrelated [earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717756/strange-byte-behavior-reading-from-a-url)).  **The problem is that when the PDF is closed, Reader throws a confirmation dialog:**

> **"Do you want to save changes to 'someFilename.pdf' before closing?"**

Obviously, there are no changes to save.  Other threads on SO have implicated extraneous, unused bytes at the tail of a initial buffer amount as the culprit.  It's not clear to me if that pattern applies in this situation, although if I stop my IDE in Debug mode, and examine the `byte[]` just before the return, there *are* a significant number of consecutive bytes with zeroes (0).

In this situation, though, I don't know how to determine what the "correct" size of the byte array *should* be.

**UPDATE:** Code example, above, now reflects a suggestion by [hoaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802512/hoaz) in the comments to use two `ByteArrayOutputStream`s.  This solves problem!

Comment: Are you sure that reusing the same BAOS for stamping and combining PDFs is a good idea?

Comment: @hoaz Actually, no, I'm not sure at all.  It's worked fine so far.  What could be the potential issue there-- or is that my problem?

Comment: I would create two BAOS instances, one for stamper, another for stitching

Comment: If after applying @hoaz ' suggestion of using separate byte array output streams (which I do support) you still get a faulty PDF, please supply a sample PDF for inspection.

Comment: I just tried two ByteArrayOutputStreams.  I will edit the question above to illustrate what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two BAOS instances, one for stamper, another for stitching.

Your problem is that you write single BAOS to itself after stamping and this mixes content.